# Return a column per date in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am using below SQL query:

```
select  brn,
        [time],
        sum(value) as [value]
from dbo.sales 
where date = '2014-12-31 00:00:00'     
    and brn = 1 
    and [time]!='ZZZZ'
group by brn, [time]
order by brn, [time]
```

And result I get is:

```
brn time    value
1   0800    0.00
1   0900    52.79
1   1000    5.73
1   1100    9.63
1   1200    200.08
```

Now I want the results for several dates (for one year-from `31-12-2014` to `31-12-2015`),

For example:

```
brn time    31/12/2014  01/01/2015  02/01/2015  03/01/2015
1   800     5.73        5.73        5.73        5.73
1   900     52.79       52.79       52.79       52.79
1   1000    5.73        5.73        5.73        5.73
1   1100    9.63        9.63        9.63        9.63
1   1200    200.08      200.08      200.08      200.08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL with pivoting:

```
select  brn,
        [time],
        sum(value) as [value],
        [date]
INTO #temp
from dbo.sales 
where brn = 1 and [time]!='ZZZZ'
     AND [date] between '2014-12-31' and '2015-12-31'
group by brn, [time], [date]


DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @col nvarchar(max)

SELECT @col = (
    SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME([date])
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH ('')
)

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM #temp
PIVOT (
    MAX([value]) FOR [date] IN ('+STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+')
) as pvt)'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks. But i get - Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".

Comment: I declare it here `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),` and it is working. Are you declare this too?

Comment: I followd below procedure, Step 1 -> opened New Query ->`select  brn,
       ---
group by brn, [time], [date]` ->executed the query. Step 2-> copied `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @col nvarchar(max)

SELECT @col = (
   ---
    MAX([value]) FOR [date] IN ('+STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+')
) as pvt)'` into new query -> executed. Step 3 -> used `EXEC sp_executesql @sql`. While doing step 3, I get this error. Is this correct procedure?

Comment: All this batch must be executed at once :)

Comment: Don't forget to `DROP TABLE #temp`

Comment: Thank you @gofr1 for the awesome solution. I have a question that how can I add another column for the dates. Like I have Value2 to show in the output.I am not using aggregation.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun You can use only on "value" in pivot, in case you need another value you can use same script, and then join to pivoting results.

Comment: Thank you @gofr1. Sorry for my lack of knowledge. If you provide an example, then it will be easy for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select brn, [time],
       sum(case when date = '2014-12-31' then value else 0 end)) as value_20141231,
       sum(case when date = '2015-01-01' then value else 0 end)) as value_20150101,
       . . .
from dbo.sales 
where brn = 1  and 
     [time] <> 'ZZZZ'
group by brn, [time]
order by brn, [time];
```

You can also restrict the dates in the `where`, using `and date in ('2014-12-31', '2015-01-01', . . .)`.

Answer (score 0):

For column names build for dates, you can create a [SQL dates table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx)
Then using dynamic SQL, you can use these as select fields
Perhaps you can check [dynamic pivot sql query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx) for how to concatenate field values from dates table into pivot query fields

Here is the SQL Script

```
DECLARE @dates nvarchar(max)
SELECT @dates =
 STUFF(
 (
    SELECT ', value as [' + convert(varchar(30), cast([date] as date), 112) + ']'
    FROM [dbo].[DateTable]('20150101', '20151231')
    for xml path('')
 ),
 1,1,'')

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = N'select brn, time, value, ' + @dates + ' from mydata'
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output is as follows

[image]

You can format the string representation of date values as you can see in [SQL Format Date](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-format-date-format-datetime-t-sql-convert-function.aspx) article.
Instead of parameter 112, you can use 103 for dd/mm/yyyy for example

I hope it helps for solution